# Python http connection problems

Tags: python, sockets, error-handling, imaplib, httpconnection

Hi so I wrote the following code that's totally running fine, until sometimes it just decides to throw this error. That's what's really tripping me out, the fact that it works fine for the most part but then sometimes just decides to fail.

A little explanation to the code, it in simple terms reads info from emails using imaplib and inputs the content into a google spreadsheet using gspread. It runs once an hour on an infinate loop. The idea is that it simply updates once an hour without me ever having to open the code. My guess is that the problem has something to do with the fact that I never end the session but I can't confirm that and also wouldn't even know how to do that without exiting the code.

Can someone explain what the errors mean and how I can avoid them?

Parts of my Code:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com', 993)
    mail.login(username, password)
    mail.list()
    mail.select('Inbox')
    result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "UNSEEN")  # (ALL/UNSEEN)
    i = len(data[0].split())
```

And also:

```
def google_auth():
    scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    return client


def get_worksheet(client):
    return client.open(WORKSHEET_NAME).worksheets()
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 358, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001C67F8523B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sheets.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v4/spreadsheets/1K65l817oObug8y82c3Yar6SZNpGVsQ5iYBlaBW75NsY?includeGridData=false (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001C67F8523B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Schedule\Schedule.py", line 204, in <module>
    loop_mail(get_mail())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Schedule\Schedule.py", line 189, in loop_mail
    worksheet = get_worksheet(client)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Schedule\Schedule.py", line 66, in get_worksheet
    return client.open(WORKSHEET_NAME).worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 127, in open
    return Spreadsheet(self, properties)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gspread\spreadsheet.py", line 33, in __init__
    metadata = self.fetch_sheet_metadata()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gspread\spreadsheet.py", line 243, in fetch_sheet_metadata
    r = self.client.request("get", url, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 59, in request
    response = getattr(self.session, method)(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 480, in request
    response = super(AuthorizedSession, self).request(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sheets.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v4/spreadsheets/1K65l817oObug8y82c3Yar6SZNpGVsQ5iYBlaBW75NsY?includeGridData=false (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001C67F8523B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

If anyone needs more details please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: The error comes from not being able to resolve `sheets.googleapis.com`, i.e. get the IP address for this host. The likely cause is some connectivity problems with the internet or that you are using an unreliable DNS server. In other words: the problem is not inside of the code but outside and the code is not robust enough to handle outside problems like faling internet connectivity.